# Implementing FileTable

Tags: sql, t-sql, implements, filetable

I've got a quick question which I hope I can get some help with.
I need to create a database and then implement `File Tables` for the following text files:

1. testFile1.txt
2. testFile2.txt
3. testFile3.txt

Once this process is finished, I simply have to delete `testFile3.txt` using `t-sql` statement.

My question is, how do I implement the text files? I understand how to create them and how to create the database, but am unsure of how to move the files into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally, you can choose one of the following techniques:

- Upload the file in specific folder in your server and store in your database only the `URL` to the file. Latter, use the `URL` for displaying the content or downloading the file
- Upload the file and store in the database in `BLOB` (`B`inary `L`arge `OB`ject) field

Each of these, has advantages and disadvantages and it is up to your situation and you to decided which technique for use.

Fortunately, when we are using `SQL Server` for storing files we have one more option which can lead to better performance - [Filestream Storage](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

This type of storage is recommended in the following situations:

- Objects that are being stored are, on average, larger than 1 MB.
- Fast read access is important.
- You are developing applications that use a middle tier for
  application logic

If your files are larger then 1 MB, I believe you should use this technique but:

> For smaller objects, storing varbinary(max) BLOBs in the database
>   often provides better streaming performance.

You can check the following [this](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/) tutorial in order to activate the storage.